# Как заставить расширятся textarea вверх по высоте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть библиотека https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize работает нормально, но не пойму, как можно заставить изменяться размеры textarea не вниз как сейчас, а вверх (того предполагает дизайн и если изменять размеры вверх, то это всё ломает.

как должно быть (картинко-пример)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Вот ещё пример рабочего textarea с авторазмером в зависимости от количества текста: https://codepen.io/Arksault/pen/bGRXEQE

и есть ещё такой вариант кода:

````
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global = global || self, global.autosize = factory());
}(this, (function () {
    var map = typeof Map === "function" ? new Map() : function () {
      var keys = [];
      var values = [];
      return {
        has: function has(key) {
          return keys.indexOf(key) > -1;
        },
        get: function get(key) {
          return values[keys.indexOf(key)];
        },
        set: function set(key, value) {
          if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            keys.push(key);
            values.push(value);
          }
        },
        "delete": function _delete(key) {
          var index = keys.indexOf(key);

          if (index > -1) {
            keys.splice(index, 1);
            values.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      };
    }();

    var createEvent = function createEvent(name) {
      return new Event(name, {
        bubbles: true
      });
    };

    try {
      new Event('test');
    } catch (e) {
      // IE does not support `new Event()`
      createEvent = function createEvent(name) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
        evt.initEvent(name, true, false);
        return evt;
      };
    }

    function assign(ta) {
      if (!ta || !ta.nodeName || ta.nodeName !== 'TEXTAREA' || map.has(ta)) return;
      var heightOffset = null;
      var clientWidth = null;
      var cachedHeight = null;

      function init() {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(ta, null);

        if (style.resize === 'vertical') {
          ta.style.resize = 'none';
        } else if (style.resize === 'both') {
          ta.style.resize = 'horizontal';
        }

        if (style.boxSizing === 'content-box') {
          heightOffset = -(parseFloat(style.paddingTop) + parseFloat(style.paddingBottom));
        } else {
          heightOffset = parseFloat(style.borderTopWidth) + parseFloat(style.borderBottomWidth);
        } // Fix when a textarea is not on document body and heightOffset is Not a Number


        if (isNaN(heightOffset)) {
          heightOffset = 0;
        }

        update();
      }

      function changeOverflow(value) {
        {
          // Chrome/Safari-specific fix:
          // When the textarea y-overflow is hidden, Chrome/Safari do not reflow the text to account for the space
          // made available by removing the scrollbar. The following forces the necessary text reflow.
          var width = ta.style.width;
          ta.style.width = '0px'; // Force reflow:
          /* jshint ignore:end */

          ta.style.width = width;
        }
        ta.style.overflowY = value;
      }

      function getParentOverflows(el) {
        var arr = [];

        while (el && el.parentNode && el.parentNode instanceof Element) {
          if (el.parentNode.scrollTop) {
            arr.push({
              node: el.parentNode,
              scrollTop: el.parentNode.scrollTop
            });
          }

          el = el.parentNode;
        }

        return arr;
      }

      function resize() {
        if (ta.scrollHeight === 0) {
          // If the scrollHeight is 0, then the element probably has display:none or is detached from the DOM.
          return;
        }

        var overflows = getParentOverflows(ta);
        var docTop = document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Needed for Mobile IE (ticket #240)

        ta.style.height = '';
        ta.style.height = ta.scrollHeight + heightOffset + 'px'; // used to check if an update is actually necessary on window.resize

        clientWidth = ta.clientWidth; // prevents scroll-position jumping

        overflows.forEach(function (el) {
          el.node.scrollTop = el.scrollTop;
        });

        if (docTop) {
          document.documentElement.scrollTop = docTop;
        }
      }

      function update() {
        resize();
        var styleHeight = Math.round(parseFloat(ta.style.height));
        var computed = window.getComputedStyle(ta, null); // Using offsetHeight as a replacement for computed.height in IE, because IE does not account use of border-box

        var actualHeight = computed.boxSizing === 'content-box' ? Math.round(parseFloat(computed.height)) : ta.offsetHeight; // The actual height not matching the style height (set via the resize method) indicates that 
        // the max-height has been exceeded, in which case the overflow should be allowed.

        if (actualHeight < styleHeight) {
          if (computed.overflowY === 'hidden') {
            changeOverflow('scroll');
            resize();
            actualHeight = computed.boxSizing === 'content-box' ? Math.round(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ta, null).height)) : ta.offsetHeight;
          }
        } else {
          // Normally keep overflow set to hidden, to avoid flash of scrollbar as the textarea expands.
          if (computed.overflowY !== 'hidden') {
            changeOverflow('hidden');
            resize();
            actualHeight = computed.boxSizing === 'content-box' ? Math.round(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ta, null).height)) : ta.offsetHeight;
          }
        }

        if (cachedHeight !== actualHeight) {
          cachedHeight = actualHeight;
          var evt = createEvent('autosize:resized');

          try {
            ta.dispatchEvent(evt);
          } catch (err) {// Firefox will throw an error on dispatchEvent for a detached element
            // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=889376
          }
        }
      }

      var pageResize = function pageResize() {
        if (ta.clientWidth !== clientWidth) {
          update();
        }
      };

      var destroy = function (style) {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', pageResize, false);
        ta.removeEventListener('input', update, false);
        ta.removeEventListener('keyup', update, false);
        ta.removeEventListener('autosize:destroy', destroy, false);
        ta.removeEventListener('autosize:update', update, false);
        Object.keys(style).forEach(function (key) {
          ta.style[key] = style[key];
        });
        map["delete"](ta);
      }.bind(ta, {
        height: ta.style.height,
        resize: ta.style.resize,
        overflowY: ta.style.overflowY,
        overflowX: ta.style.overflowX,
        wordWrap: ta.style.wordWrap
      });

      ta.addEventListener('autosize:destroy', destroy, false); // IE9 does not fire onpropertychange or oninput for deletions,
      // so binding to onkeyup to catch most of those events.
      // There is no way that I know of to detect something like 'cut' in IE9.

      if ('onpropertychange' in ta && 'oninput' in ta) {
        ta.addEventListener('keyup', update, false);
      }

      window.addEventListener('resize', pageResize, false);
      ta.addEventListener('input', update, false);
      ta.addEventListener('autosize:update', update, false);
      ta.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
      ta.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
      map.set(ta, {
        destroy: destroy,
        update: update
      });
      init();
    }

    function destroy(ta) {
      var methods = map.get(ta);

      if (methods) {
        methods.destroy();
      }
    }

    function update(ta) {
      var methods = map.get(ta);

      if (methods) {
        methods.update();
      }
    }

    var autosize = null; // Do nothing in Node.js environment and IE8 (or lower)

    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || typeof window.getComputedStyle !== 'function') {
      autosize = function autosize(el) {
        return el;
      };

      autosize.destroy = function (el) {
        return el;
      };

      autosize.update = function (el) {
        return el;
      };
    } else {
      autosize = function autosize(el, options) {
        if (el) {
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(el.length ? el : [el], function (x) {
            return assign(x);
          });
        }

        return el;
      };

      autosize.destroy = function (el) {
        if (el) {
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(el.length ? el : [el], destroy);
        }

        return el;
      };

      autosize.update = function (el) {
        if (el) {
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(el.length ? el : [el], update);
        }

        return el;
      };
    }

    var autosize$1 = autosize;

    return autosize$1;

})));```
````

Comment: что означает "не вниз, а вверх"? можно картинку, что вы имеете ввиду? С данной библиотекой не знаком, но судя по всему она лишь задает размер блоку. Далее уже вы его позиционируете как вам надо, не так ли?

Comment: @АлександрРодин вот https://d.radikal.ru/d33/2110/90/2ed425c58c8b.png

и нужно чтобы сам блок был зафиксирован в нижней точке.

Comment: textarea {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
будет зафиксирован в нижней точке

Comment: @АлександрРодин да ничего подобного, пробовал. не робит. его по прежнему растягивает вниз по высоте, а не вверх.

Comment: скрипт не растягивает textarea вниз или вверх, он задает ей высоту, а как позиционируется ваш блок уже зависит от стилей, которые вы пропишете.

Comment: @Alexandr ну так я прописал position absolute и position relative на родителя, но не робит. хорошо, как в таком случае заставить задавать высоту не вниз, а вверх.

видео проблемы в действии: https://radikal.ru/video/6NdwssnFaCJ